# Application of Compound Poisson Process

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the following application problem:

The life T (hours) of the lightbulb in an overhead projector follows
an Exp(10)-distribution. During a normal week it is used a Po(12)-
distributed number of lectures lasting exactly one hour each. Find the
probability that a projector with a newly installed lightbulb functions
throughout a normal week (without replacing the lightbulb).

My attempt at a solution:
First I compute unconditional distribution of $X$:
$P(X=x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X=x|M=x)*f_{M}(x)dx$.
In this case $P(X=x|M=x)=\frac{e^{-m}m^{x}}{x!}$ and $f_{M}(x)=e^{-m/a}*a^{-1}$, where $m=12$ and $a=10$ as defined in the question.  After the substitution and some algebraic manipulation which involved creating a gamma distribution within the integral, I computed that $P(X=x)=(1-Q)*(Q)^{x}$ where $Q=\frac{1}{a+1}$, hence $P(X=x)$ ~ $Geometric(Q)$.

I just don't know where to go from there.  Once I have this distribution how do I determine the probability the light function throughout a normal week?  Do I just substitute x=7 into the geometric distribution function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We condition on the number of lectures. The probability that the bulb is still alive at the end of the week, **given** there are $k$ lectures, is $e^{-k/10}$. Thus the probability it lasts the week is
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-12}\frac{(12)^k}{k!} e^{-k/10}.$$
This infinite series has a simple closed form, for $(12)^ke^{-k/10}=\left(12e^{-1/10}\right)^k$, and $\sum_0^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}=e^t$.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I had typos, $10$ instead of $12$ at a couple of places. Fixed.